# Command to find a function in a file and print its contents

Tags: regex, linux, awk, grep, sh

I am looking for a grep, sed, or awk command that will recursively search through files for a function name and if a function name is matched then print the contents of that function.

```
int function_name(){
    //Body
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
       //this too
    }
    //with this
}
```

I want to be able use a terminal command that if I don't know what file function_name()`is in I can search for`function_name()` and it will print out

```
//Body
for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
    //this too
}
//with this
```

What I am using now that kind of works is `grep -r -A 100 "function_name()" *` but that always shows 100 lines after finding the function. The problem is that some functions are less than 100 and it shows stuff I don't need and some are larger than 100 lines which get cut off.

I am not too familiar with Regular Expressions but I would like it to print everything between the curly braces `{ Print This }`, even if there are curly braces within the outer most curly braces.

Comment: Normal regular expressions cannot match braces. Some newer regular expression engines can, but these extensions are not available in `grep` or `awk` or `sed`. You might be able to do it by matching indent levels though.

Comment: The only surefire way to get it right is to find a parser for the language you're parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in comments, regular expressions available in the standard UNIX tools can't match braces. Things get even more ugly when you consider braces in strings, comments...

Here is a possible solution using indent matching. If you save this as `findfunc.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
  printing = 0;
  indent = ""; 
}
{
  if (printing) {
    if ($0 ~ ("^"indent"}$")) {
      printing = 0;
    } else {
      print;                                                                    
    }   
  } else if ($0 ~ ("^[^(]*"name"\\(.*\\)\\s*{$")) {
    indent = gensub(/^(\s*).*$/, "\\1", $0);
    printing = 1;
  }
}
```

you could invoke it like this:

```
awk -f findfunc.awk name=function_name source.c
```

Comment: This works great! How would I go about editing `else if ($0 ~ ("^[^(]*"name"\\(.*\\)\\s*{$"))` to allow the `{` to be on the next line?